# Using Python - setup list to store 30 student surnames as well as test marks for test1 and test2 which are both out of 50

Tags: python

I'm trying to help my son (we're both really new to Python) with some Python homework, he's just started coding, so have I it seems. The question is as follows:

Setup one dimensional array/list to store the following:

30 student surnames

student marks for test 1 - out of 50

student marks for test 2 - out of 50

Total score for each student

Input and score the student's marks for test 1 and 2. All marks must be validated on entry and invalid marks rejected.

We are able to create a list for the student surnames but not sure how to go from there when creating two more lists which have marks for test 1 and 2 that need to be linked to a specific surname. They have not learnt about dictionaries yet, during my research I saw that this may be an option but can't be used to solve the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include some minimal code and show us what you have tried. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you saying you need to get all four values (surname, test1, test2, total score) in one 1d list?  or 4 separate 1d lists?  Also what constitutes the validation procedure for marks?  And how is "input" received - literally using raw input from the keyboard, or is there a list of data to use as starting values?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The information in the OP is all we've been given to work with. We haven't been given a list of data for starting values so will use random data to test the if the program works correctly. How I understand the question is that we need to input the names of 30 student surnames along with values for test 1 and 2. The total score will be calculated using the values inputed for test 1 and test 2. I can create lists to get the surnames and test scores but how does one link the test scores to the relevant student?

Comment: If you can't use dictionaries or multi-dimensional lists, you'll just need to keep track of the index for a given student and make sure that student's scores are in the same index in the other lists.  Then use something like @Joe Iddon's second approach below.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help. Going to work with it and see where we get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dictionaries:

```
people = {}
for _ in range(30):
    surname = input('surname: ')
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        try:
            test_1 = int(input('test 1 score: '))
            test_2 = int(input('test 2 score: '))
            if not (0 <= test_1 <= 50 and 0 <= test_2 <= 50): raise ValueError
            ok = True
        except ValueError:
            print('please enter integers between 0 and 50')
    people[surname] = {'test 1': test_1, 'test 2': test_2, 'total': test_1 + test_2}
```

and then, after all the entries, you can later get results easily with something like:

```
people['charles']['test 1']
people = {}
for _ in range(30):
    surname = input('surname: ')
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        try:
            test_1 = int(input('test 1 score: '))
            test_2 = int(input('test 2 score: '))
            if not 0 < test_1 < 50 and 0 < test_2 < 50: raise ValueError
            ok = True
        except ValueError:
            print('please enter integers between 0 and 50')
    people[surname] = {'test 1': test_1, 'test 2': test_2, 'total': test_1 + test_2}
```

---

If you are not supposed to use dictionaries, then the next best method would probably be to use four lists: one for surnames, two for test scores and one for the total scores.

That would look somehthing like:

```
people = []
test_1_scores = []
test_2_scores = []
total_scores = []
for _ in range(30):
    surname = input('surname: ')
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        try:
            test_1 = int(input('test 1 score: '))
            test_2 = int(input('test 2 score: '))
            if not (0 <= test_1 <= 50 and 0 <= test_2 <= 50): raise ValueError
            ok = True
        except ValueError:
            print('please enter integers between 0 and 50')
    people.append(surname)
    test_1_scores.append(test_1)
    test_2_scores.append(test_2)
    total_scores.append(test_1 + test_2)
```

and then you can get results through indexing the desired list with the corresponding index of a surname in the `people` list:

```
test_1_scores[people.index('charles')]
```

Comment: @andrew_reece my bad, just testing them now, will fix

Comment: Thank you for help @JoeIddon, really appreciate it. Upvoted but my reputation to low for it to register.

Comment: @Ninjahugs You can accept the answer which shows this helps by clicking the grey tick (it will go green)